# how to bind a pageshow event using Ajax in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i want to bind some events to my page using jQuery an jQuery mobile. But I don't understand the procedure. I can bind random events to my documents and it still executes the binding function. Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/nRkCQ/2/

The result is: At my first page i do a $.mobile.loadPage("secondpage",...) and at my secondpage I have the command $(document).bind("pageshow", alert("alert Message");
Because of this problem the pageshow event is already fired after the loading of the second page. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `$.bind()` method expects a function *reference*. You're using a  *statement* `alert('blah')` , so it is executed immediately.

To have your callback called when the event is triggered, you should do something like:

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function() { alert('message'); });
```